# Kotlin contract infer return value instead of argument value

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-contracts

I have a function that looks something like:

```
fun MyInput?.toOutput() : Output? {
  if (this == null) return null
  return Output(this.someValue)
}
```

In places where I know that my `MyInput` is non-null (for example, inside a method that takes a `input: MyInput` as an arg), I'd like to be able to use `input.toOutput` as `Output` instead of `Output?`

I've tried using

```
contract {
  returnsNotNull() implies (this@toOutput != null)
}
```

But that has the implication backwards. That tells me that if `toOutput` returns a non-null type, that my `input` was non-null. I want to tell the analyzer things about the return value based on the arguments. In Java, I could use `org.jetbrains.annotations.@Contract("null -> null ; !null -> !null")` to accomplish this.

Is there a way to do this in Kotlin?

Comment: Note that for this, you might as well not offer `MyInput?.toOutput()` at all.  Just provide `MyInput.toOutput()`, and then let callers write `myInput?.toOutput()` with the question mark.  That'll make the nullability behavior much more obvious to users as well as letting you avoid this entire issue.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That's a great idea, but would it work to call `toOutput` from Java?

Comment: It would work in the sense that you'd have to check for null on the Java end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need contracts for this. You just need to make a non-nullable overload. Like this:

```
fun MyInput?.toOutput(): Output? {
  if (this == null) return null
  return Output(this.someValue)
}

fun MyInput.toOutput(): Output = Output(this.someValue)
```

However, this will not work out of the box on the JVM, because the function signatures will clash. To make it work, you have to give one of the functions a new name with the `@JvmName` annotation. For example:

```
@JvmName("toOutputNonNull")
fun MyInput.toOutput(): Output = Output(this.someValue)
```

You will still be able to call it like `input.toOutput()` from Kotlin, but it will become something like `FileNameKt.toOutputNonNull(input)` if you call it from Java.